# Hide the standard new button in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

Is it possible to hide the standard new button for the object tab in Salesforce1?

Comment: I propose you update the title and description to better match with what you described in the answer comments. Plus add a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

you can't remove that button but can override that to call any VF page on click of that button.

Comment: Right! But, if I want to override it with a URL navigating to the standard page layout it just refreshes. Ex: Pagereference pf = new Pagereference('/'+Label.Object_Id+'/e?RecordType='+Label.RecordType_Id);

Comment: Can you please put the code you have used for this ?

Comment: I have overridden the new button by calling a VF Page. The controller returns the page reference based on the record type id.                                          Pagereference pf = new Pagereference('/'+Label.Object_Id+'/e?RecordType='+Label.RecordType_Id);